# Using django-angular with django-bootstrap3

Tags: django, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I'm using [django-angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) for a project and wanted to use [django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3) with django forms. I want to show an angular powered model form in the template, the code for which is:

```
class InfoForm(NgModelFormMixin, NgFormValidationMixin, NgModelForm):
    form_name = 'infoForm'
    class Meta:
        model = models.InfoModel
```

To display it using django-bootstrap3, I used `{% bootstrap_form form %}` in my template but that isn't working the way it should:

[image]

What can be done to make the two work together properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging a lot into the code of django-angular and going through some of the previous issues[1], I found a graceful solution for this. Turns out, [django-angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) already has a `Bootstrap3FormMixin` which provides a method as_div which can be simply used to render angular-powered forms with bootstrap3 styling. Now, showing forms is easy as `{{ form.as_div }}` (no need for django-bootstrap3 or anything else). The only requirement is for the form to have `Bootstrap3FormMixin`.

Anyone looking for more background for this can find the relevant issues here:

[1][django-angular Issue #51](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular/issues/51)

[2][django-angular Issue #161](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular/issues/51)